# EF Core 2 Not Saving Related Entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have an implicit one to many relationship set up between Template and TemplateParameters. As far as I can tell, I am following conventions. However, when I save a Template, the children are not discovered and saved with it.

```
public class Template
    {
        #region Properties
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Published { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }
        public int Shares { get; set; }
        public int Downloads { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Navigation
        //navigation properties
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Wave> Waves { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TemplateParameter> TemplateParameters;
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> Subscribers; 
        #endregion
    }
public class TemplateParameter
    {
        public int TemplateParameterId { get; set; }
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double? Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        //navigation properties
        public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
        [Route("SaveTemplate")]
        public TemplateViewModel SaveTemplate([FromBody] TemplateViewModel vm)
        {
            //get the current userId        
            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).Result;
            var token = User;

            //map params
            var parameters = vm.Parameters.Select(r => new TemplateParameter()
            {
                Name = r.Name,
                Description = r.Description,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
            }).ToList();

            //map the vm to the model
            var template = new Template()
            {
                Name = vm.Name,
                Description = vm.Description,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = user.Id,
                TemplateParameters = parameters,
            };

            //save the template
            template = _templateService.SaveTemplate(template);
            //map id back to the view model
            vm.TemplateID = template.TemplateId;
            return vm;
        }

 public Template SaveTemplate(Template template)
        {
            _context.Templates.Add(template);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return template;
        }
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here? The template saves fine, but the child collections does not. I'm using the same pattern elsewhere in my project and it seems to work without issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried making the navigation properties inside `Template` virtual?

Comment: I have, but I don't think it matters as that seems to relate to lazy loading.

Comment: I have to test it when I get home, but I think I realized what I did wrong - no get set on the navigation property.

Comment: Any updates on this?